# Segment fault with execvp

Tags: c

I try to use execvp to create a repository which is given as parameter. But i get some segfault (core dump) that i can't solve in the following code :

```
#include <sys/stat.h>  //mkdir
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>  //perror
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int i;
char *args[6] = {"tar","-xzvf", strcpy(args[2],argv[0]), "-C", "/home/bg/Desktop  /Project/", NULL};
FILE *fp;
char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
char *result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
char* strings[MAX]; 


int result_code = mkdir("/home/bg/Desktop/Project/", 0777); 
umask(mask); 

if(result_code ==-1) {
  perror(argv[0]);
  printf("Erreur dans la création du répertoire/n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(result_code==0){

printf("Le répertoire a bien été crée \n");

execvp(*args,args); 

fp = fopen("/home/bg/Desktop/Project/meta", "r"); 
if (!fp) {perror("problème avec le fichier");
          fprintf(stderr, "Erreur dans l'ouverture du fichier\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) { 
           printf("On récupère une ligne de taille %zu :\n", read);
           printf("%s", line);

           if(strchr (line,'#') != NULL) {

           }

           else if (strchr (line,'$') != NULL) {
             strings[i] = strdup(line);
             i++;

           }

           else if (strchr (line,'>') != NULL) {
             result = strdup(line);
           }

       }

unlink("meta");
free(line);
free(result);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  }


}
```

I tried to use char** but execvp doesn't fit it.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this even compile??

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a problem with the following code:

```
char *args[6] = {"tar","-xzvf", strncpy(args[2],argv[0]), "-C", "/home/bg/Desktop  /Project/", NULL};
```

Specifically, with the `strncpy` for two reasons: 1) `strncpy()` takes three arguments, and you have only specified 2, and 2) it is attempting to copy `argv[0]` (the program name) into `args[2]`, which is an array of pointers, not a buffer to contain the program name.

Comment: However, `args[2]` isn't 'an array of pointers'; it is just a pointer that hasn't yet been initialized (it is the element being initialized by the `strncpy()`).  Bad indeed.  The initializer should simply be `argv[0]` if the program name is desired at that point in the argument list.